# Fortran code crashes from a simple deallocate line

Tags: fortran

I'm modifying an open source program and it is crashing under certain settings when it executes a very simple line.  I cannot understand why this line would cause the program to crash.  The line is

```
IF (allocated(bec%k))  DEALLOCATE(bec%k)
```

This line is executed multiple times before crashing, but after a certain point for certain program settings it crashes the program.  bec%k is always allocated when this line executes.  The compiler is gfortran.

The terminal output that results form the error says:

```
free(): invalid next size (normal)
Program received signal SIGABRT: Process abort signal.
Backtrace for this error:
#0  0x7f428db872da in ???
#1  0x7f428db86503 in ???
#2  0x7f428cfe4f1f in ???
#3  0x7f428cfe4e97 in ???
#4  0x7f428cfe6800 in ???
#5  0x7f428d02f896 in ???
#6  0x7f428d036909 in ???
#7  0x7f428d03e0ac in ???
#8  0x56366a04e2b6 in __becmod_MOD_deallocate_bec_type
    at /home/john/Desktop/q-e-qe-6.3/Modules/becmod.f90:401
#9  0x563669e734f4 in update_hamiltonian_
    at /home/john/Desktop/ce-tddft-6.3-another-copy/src/update_ham.f90:61
#10  0x563669e7ab70 in molecule_optical_absorption_
    at /home/john/Desktop/ce-tddft-6.3-another-copy/src/molecule_optical_absorption.f90:538
#11  0x563669e6e2c4 in tddft_main
    at /home/john/Desktop/ce-tddft-6.3-another-copy/src/tddft_main.f90:118
#12  0x563669e6de6e in main
    at /home/john/Desktop/ce-tddft-6.3-another-copy/src/tddft_main.f90:19
```

I also get the following error message in the output file:

```
mpirun noticed that process rank 0 with PID 0 on node JohnUbuntu exited on signal 6 (Aborted).
```

In case you are interested, here is the subroutine that the line is part of as well as the bec datatype

```
!-----------------------------------------------------------------------
  SUBROUTINE deallocate_bec_type (bec)
    !-----------------------------------------------------------------------
    !
    USE mp, ONLY: mp_get_comm_null
    IMPLICIT NONE
    TYPE (bec_type) :: bec
    !
    bec%comm = mp_get_comm_null()
    bec%nbnd = 0
    !
    IF (allocated(bec%r))  DEALLOCATE(bec%r)
    IF (allocated(bec%nc)) DEALLOCATE(bec%nc)
    IF (allocated(bec%k))  DEALLOCATE(bec%k)
    !
    RETURN
    !
  END SUBROUTINE deallocate_bec_type


  TYPE bec_type
     REAL(DP),   ALLOCATABLE :: r(:,:)    ! appropriate for gammaonly
     COMPLEX(DP),ALLOCATABLE :: k(:,:)    ! appropriate for generic k
     COMPLEX(DP),ALLOCATABLE :: nc(:,:,:)   ! appropriate for noncolin
     INTEGER :: comm
     INTEGER :: nbnd
     INTEGER :: nproc
     INTEGER :: mype
     INTEGER :: nbnd_loc
     INTEGER :: ibnd_begin
  END TYPE bec_type
```

Anny suggestions about what is causing it or what to do would be much appreciated.

Comment: Compile your code with debugging options, e.g., -fcheck=all -g.  Run under a debugger such as gdb, and get a real backtrace.

Comment: Usually, in such a case, the actual bug occurred BEFORE that instruction and has corrupted the memory (like writing out the bounds of any array)

Comment: The suggiestion is to follow Steve's instructipns above and to supply a [mcve]. This is a typical *heap corruption* and you can fiind many similar duplicates here. Ypu should use the debugging options before coming here.

Comment: The error message you copy-pasted "free(): invalid next size"  is a quite certain signal that you have memory corruption. As Steve mentioned, recompile with "-fcheck=all -g -Og -Wall" and rerun.